# generate numbers

Tags: distribution

I want to generate numbers in some distribution patterns such as Exponential,Normal,Triangular etc. Please help me to this? are there any software to generate numbers?

regards,
nilani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can do that

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/statistical-functions-HP005203066.aspx

Alternatively, you can look up the expression for the distributions and implement them in your favourite programming language with a range of random variables. Should be simple

Comment: Excel is known to have poor performance generating random numbers, since it uses an algorithm that's obsolete on modern hardware (and possibly not even correctly implemented at that): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistics/Numerical_Methods/Numerics_in_Excel#Assessing_Random_Number_Generator_of_Excel

Answer (score 1):

The book Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation (out of print) is available freely online:

http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html

It contains algorithms for specific distributions as well as general theorems that you might find useful.

Also, there are probably libraries that will do this for you. If you specify what language you're using, someone may be able to point you in the right direction.